# Python Iterate through list of dictionaries and save to db

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Im new to python and trying to save raw post data in python into mysql.

I want to iterate over each element in the json that is posted and save all the data to DB.

**json list of objects:**  (30 objects with each 11 columns)

```
[
 {
   "col1":7878,
   "col2":"c004979d3969a86a8fdcda2f92eb39e3",
   "col3":"b000yht23",
    ...
   "col11":2

 },
 {
   "col1":7878,
   "col2":"c004979d3969a86a8fdcda2f92eb39e3",
   "col3":"b000yht23"
    ...
   "col11":43 
 },
 #upto 30 objects
 ....
]
```

**'json_test' table desc:**

> CREATE TABLE `json_test` (
>
> ```
> `col1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col4` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col5` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col6` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col7` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col8` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col9` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col10` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>
> `col11` varchar(200) NOT NULL
> ```
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

**UPDATED to save data to DB:**

My py code looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, abort, request 
import json
import pymysql

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def foo():
    jsonobject=request.json
    if not jsonobject:
        abort(400)

# load- converts JSON source text to a Python value
#readable_json=json.dumps(jsonobject)

#UPDATED with column_names
k=0
for i in jsonobject:
    # Connect to the database
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='10.20.3.4', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='python_db')


    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            column_names = ['col1','col2','col3',...'col11']
            column_names_str = ', '.join(column_names)
            binds_str = ', '.join('%s' for _ in range(len(column_names)))
            sql=("INSERT INTO `json_test` ({column_names})" \
                  " VALUES({binds})"
            .format(column_names=column_names_str,binds=binds_str))   
            for data_dict in jsonobject:
            values = [data_dict[column_name]
                      for column_name in column_names]

            cursor.execute(sql, values)
            print("Insert successfull!")
            #UPDATED 
            k+=1
            conn.commit()

    finally:
        conn.close()


return "Insert successful"
#return json.dumps(jsonobject)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='10.22.1.168',debug=True,port=7845)
```

**UPDATED code result:**

Only the last record seems to be inserting

Comment: it will be great to see your `json_test` table declaration and `jsonobject` example

Comment: have updated with the table desc and json dicts

Comment: in your table definition `col1` is `varchar`, while in jsonobject it has `int` value, should it be converted to `str`?

Comment: have you tried to modify given answer with columns names specified?

Comment: read my answer again and find out what was missed

Comment: have updated the code base changing the sql objects, seems that only 1 record (last rec) is inserting, when i printed out the values, all 30 object values are coming, but during insertion only last one is inserting!

Comment: updated answer, please, just copy-paste it this time and tell me if something went wrong

Comment: Could you tell in the code why only the last record is inserting , so that i can accept your answer

Comment: in [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44264978/3)? because you were getting `jsonobject[0]` on each iteration

Comment: Oh man, i am using pycharm ide, there seems to be no error in indentations, which ide u using?

Comment: i am using PyCharm too

Comment: ok anyways thanks for the suggestions buddy, i accepted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this mess

```
#UPDATED with column_names
k=0
for i in jsonobject:
    # Connect to the database
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='10.20.3.4', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='python_db')


    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            column_names = ['col1','col2','col3',...'col11']
            column_names_str = ', '.join(column_names)
            binds_str = ', '.join('%s' for _ in range(len(column_names)))
            sql=("INSERT INTO `json_test` ({column_names})" \
                  " VALUES({binds})"
            .format(column_names=column_names_str,binds=binds_str))   
            for data_dict in jsonobject:
            values = [data_dict[column_name]
                      for column_name in column_names]

            cursor.execute(sql, values)
            print("Insert successfull!")
            #UPDATED 
            k+=1
            conn.commit()

    finally:
        conn.close()


return "Insert successful"
```

with

```
try:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        columns_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6',
                         'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10', 'col11']
        columns_names_str = ', '.join(columns_names)
        binds_str = ', '.join('%s' for _ in range(len(columns_names)))
        for data_dict in jsonobject:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO json_test ({columns_names}) "
                   "VALUES ({binds})"
                   .format(columns_names=columns_names_str,
                           binds=binds_str))
            values = [data_dict[column_name]
                      for column_name in columns_names]
            cursor.execute(sql, values)
        print("Insert successfull!")
        conn.commit()
finally:
    conn.close()
```

---

## Summation

- `k` object is redundant,
- also name `i` is unclear and makes me think like it is some kind of index when it is not: it is a `dict` object,
- we don't need to create connection for each object from `jsonobject` because it is an expensive operation,
- we don't need to create `sql` object on each iteration as well (it remains unchanged),
- storing columns names in `list`/`tuple` will save us from writing them twice: in a query and in values extraction.
- creating binds `str`

  ```
  %s, %s, ...
  ```

  dynamically based on number of columns saves us from typo when we've missed/added too many bind aliases

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Azat, but can u please clarify like what does   [data_dict[column_name] in values do , i mean where is 'column_name'..?

Comment: are you wondering what [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) does, or what?

Comment: i was wondering is it a typo in column_name under values... values = [data_dict[column_name]  column_name or columns_names

Comment: we are getting single `column_name` from `columns_names` list, so there is no typo

Comment: I want to do something similar to this. What I don't understand is ``` conn = pymysql.connect(host='10.20.3.4', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='python_db') ``` Will this always be the case or should I specify other credentials? Also, pymysql does not have an attribute connect()

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh: yes, those credentials should be specified by you, feel free to post another question and post a link here and we will try to help in your particular case

Comment: Thank you, I am new to json and peewee I do have a special case.. I'll post my question now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895060/peewee-orm-sqlite-create-db-with-list-of-nested-dictionaries-from-google-analyti

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps` does the *opposite* of what you claim; it converts a Python object into a string.

The result of `request.json` is already a Python datastructure. You don't need to do anything else with it.

Comment: so if i need to iterate over all the elementsis it right if i use : for i in jsonobject:   but still i get same error and remove the line readable_json=...

Comment: I have updated the code @Daniel, but data not saving for multiple json objects